# Why does the changing of the position in the transform component of the car not move my car object in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Spare me I'm a beginner !.
In my game the distance between the eye and the car determines the speed of the car. The eye is moved by the mouse. There is a max of units to move per sec in x or y direction (MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond). The distant in x and y direction between the eye and the car relative to max distance in x (Xmax) and y (Ymax) direction determine the speed in those directions. 
There are no error messages in the console, but the car (pitstopCar5Pos) doesn't move. I guess it's in the last 2 lines. What am I doing wrong ?.

[image: picture: Game working in Unity]

```
 //  
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineCarEye : MonoBehaviour {
//Script for PitstopCar5 GameObject

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // MaxSpeed left or right
        const float MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond = 5;
        // Width playfield in world coordinates
        const float XMax = 20;
        // Height playfield in world coordinates
        const float YMax = 10;

        //Draw the line between eye and car
        LineRenderer lr = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        Vector3 blueEyePos = GameObject.Find("BlueEye").transform.position;
        Vector3 pitstopCar5Pos = transform.position;

        lr.SetPosition(0, blueEyePos);
        lr.SetPosition(1, pitstopCar5Pos);

        //Move the car depending on the x-component, y-component of the line and MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond
        pitstopCar5Pos.x += ((blueEyePos.x - pitstopCar5Pos.x)*MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond*Time.deltaTime)/XMax;
        pitstopCar5Pos.y += ((blueEyePos.y - pitstopCar5Pos.y)*MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond*Time.deltaTime)/YMax;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `x` and `y` value of the `pitstopCar5Pos`  variable type expecting it to move the `GameObject` but it doesn't and it shouldn't.

The reason for that is because `pitstopCar5Pos` is a type of `Vector3` and `Vector3` is a `struct`. `struct` is a value type unlike like `class` which is a reference type.

Once you did:

```
Vector3 pitstopCar5Pos = transform.position;
```

a copy of the position is made and returned to a new `Vector3` instance. This new `Vector3` *is no longer linked to the `transform.position`*.

To fix that, assign the `Vector3` back to `transform.position` after changing it.

```
pitstopCar5Pos.x += ((blueEyePos.x - pitstopCar5Pos.x)*MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond*Time.deltaTime)/XMax;
pitstopCar5Pos.y += ((blueEyePos.y - pitstopCar5Pos.y)*MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond*Time.deltaTime)/YMax;

transform.position = pitstopCar5Pos;
```

Comment: Thx for the complete explanation, I understand it and changed the code and the damn thing is riding, I'm so happy, thx again !!.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. Fixed it. struct = value type. class = reference type. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `Vector3` and assigning `transform.position` to it.

```
Vector3 pitstopCar5Pos = transform.position;
```

Then you change the values of this new `Vector3`

```
pitstopCar5Pos.x += ((blueEyePos.x - pitstopCar5Pos.x)*MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond*Time.deltaTime)/XMax;
pitstopCar5Pos.y += ((blueEyePos.y - pitstopCar5Pos.y)*MoveMaxUnitsPerSecond*Time.deltaTime)/YMax;
```

This does however, not change the value of `transform.position`

What you need to do is

```
transform.position = pitstopCar5Pos;
```